# React native - import function to component that uses "this"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function called getGooglePlaces....that is currently sitting within a class that represents a component.
It is quite complex so I want to move it out to a different file (helper file) and import it.
However I get error message "Cannot read property 'refreshing' of undefined".
Im assuming its referring to 'this'....so how do I make it so my component recognizes 'this' from the function thats being imported? (as if the 'this' belongs to the component that is importing it)

```
  getGooglePlaces = () => {

    //add loading spinner unless we are refreshing
    if (this.state.refreshing === false) this.setState({ loading: true });

    //hit google places api
    const uri = `etcetc`;

    fetch(uri)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then((dataBack) => {
        this.setState({
          data: uniqueDataArray,
          loading: false, 
          refreshing: false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your this is referring to the class instance where it used to be. Since you transfered the function outside of your class scope, the function no longer has access to the `this`.

A way would be to pass the instance of the `this` into the function call.

Inside your class you can call like below:

```
    getGooglePlaces(this);
```

Or a different way is just to refactor getGooglePlaces to accept a callback function like below:

```
function getGooglePlaces(callback) {

    //hit google places api
    const uri = `etcetc`;

    fetch(uri)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then((dataBack) => {
        callback(dataBack); // passed to calling scope
    }
}
```

call it like below from class:

```
if (this.state.refreshing === false) this.setState({ loading: true });


getGooglePlaces(function(uniqueDataArray) { // received when callback called 
    this.setState({
      data: uniqueDataArray,
      loading: false, 
      refreshing: false
    })
})
```

This way you maintain the `this` inside the proper scope without needing to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you move the function out of the component, its `this` context will not be the React component. I'd suggest passing the state you want to reference into the function

```
function getGooglePlaces(componentState) => {
  ...


  return { 
    data: uniqueDataArray,
    loading: false, 
    refreshing: false
  }
}
```

and then set the state of your component with the result the function returns

```
class MyReactComponent extends Component {
  ...
  const result = getGooglePlaces(this.state)
  this.setState(result)
  ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you.  I actually ended up using a third approach....I added the below line of code into constructor and it works great

```
this.getGooglePlaces = getGooglePlaces.bind(this);
```